Do Azure OpenAI Service's content filters depend on the OpenAI GPT models? Or are they independent?
Do Azure OpenAI Service's content filters  depend on the OpenAI GPT models? Or are they independent?
In other words, is the moderation done by those content filters the same for any GPT model or does it depend on the GPT model?

Yes, Azure OpenAI content filters are independent of the Azure OpenAI GPT models.
As we read on Microsoft Learn platform:

The content filtering system integrated into Azure OpenAI Service runs alongside the core models, including DALL-E image generation models. It uses an ensemble of multi-class classification models... and optional binary classifiers.

The moderation done by the filters depends only on their configuration severity and not on the model used in the deployment.
